# EXTJS 3.4 Support for Edge Browser Detection

Tags: javascript, extjs, microsoft-edge, browser-detection

I can detect if the browser is `IE` using `Ext.isIE` method using ExtJS 3.4. Is there any way to detect if the browser is Microsoft Edge using ExtJS 3.4.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and you'll get help
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ext.browser.name to check the browser.
In case of Edge browser, it will return "Edge"

For eg.

```
if(Ext.browser.name.toLowerCase() == "edge"){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for MS Edge was added in EXT JS 5.1.2

EXT JS 5.1.2 version is able to detect the Edge browser using **Ext.isEdge** and **Ext.browser**

So as per the documentation, EXT JS 3.4 will not detect the Edge browser. You need to upgrade EXT JS 5.1.2 version to fulfil your requirement.

Reference:

[Announcing Ext JS 5.1.2: Including Microsoft Edge Support](https://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-ext-js-5-1-2-including-microsoft-edge-support/)